# php FileType if not working

Tags: php, image, file, upload

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
        echo "
        <center>
        <div style=\"font-size:300%\">The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.</div>
        </center>
        ";


        if($imageFileType == "jpg" && $imageFileType == "png" && $imageFileType == "jpeg" && $imageFileType == "gif" && $imageFileType == ".jpg") {
            echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
            echo "<center><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;url=http://79.176.32.166/?img=". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "\"/></center>";
        }else{
            echo "<center><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;url=http://79.176.32.166/?rarOrZip=". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."\"/></center>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=http://eib5i7knmc5utt3e.onion\"/>";
    }
}
```

hello i try to teleport user when his equal to png or jpg for example.. but it just not working for me

Comment: So where is `$imageFileType` defined?

Comment: change the && in conditional statement to ||  for all of the &&   image files cannot be  all types only one so saying "and" makes no sense. This will always evaluate to false unless you change to or "||"

Comment: @Danimal thank you work

Comment: be sure to upvote!

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.